# Fill WPF ItemsControl Property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have defined a **readonly** dependency property of type ToolBar to my control.

How can I populate this ToolBar with Items in xaml code?
The ToolBar is created in constructor of my control and is readonly.

I can write

```
<ToolBar>
    <MenuItem/>
    <Button/>
</ToolBar>
```

but when I write

```
<my:myControl.MyToolBar>
    <MenuItem/>
    <Button/>
</my:myControl.MyToolBar>
```

the error says 'Property MyToolBar does not support values of 'Button/MenuItem''

Comment: write `<ToolBar><MenuItem/></ToolBar>` inside `<my:myControl.MyToolBar>`...`</my:myControl.MyToolBar>`

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the ToolBar which is set to MyToolBar gets created in MyControl-Constructor and is readonly, so this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom `ToolBar` control it should inherit `ToolBar` or `HeaderedItemsControl`

```
public class MyToolBar : HeaderedItemsControl
{
}
```

And if `MyToolBar` is a property of a control, you should set it to a `ToolBar` value:

```
<my:myControl.MyToolBar>
    <ToolBar>
        <MenuItem/>
        <Button/>
    </ToolBar>
</my:myControl.MyToolBar>
```

**Edit:**

> I have defined a readonly dependency property of type ToolBar to my control. How can I populate this ToolBar with Items in xaml code?

You can't. This is not supported in XAML:

[WPF: Cannot set items of a read-only collection in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419422/wpf-cannot-set-items-of-a-read-only-collection-in-xaml)

Remember that XAML is only a *markup* language.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the ToolBar which is set to MyToolBar gets created in MyControl-Constructor and is readonly, so this is not possible

Comment: Then you can't populate the collection in XAML. This is not supported.